# how can I put a rotated image in imageview (JavaFx)?

Tags: java, image, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

when I rotate the image in the imageview it becomes cuted from the corners, this is the function of rotating the image , I work with BufferedImage then I convert it to Image :

```
public BufferedImage rotate(BufferedImage bImage, int angle) {
    int w = bImage.getWidth();
    int h = bImage.getHeight();
    AffineTransform transform = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(angle), w / 2, h / 2);
    AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(transform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
    BufferedImage bImage2 = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    op.filter(bImage, bImage2);
    }
    int a = bImage2.getWidth();
    int b = bImage2.getHeight();
    view.setFitWidth(a);
    view.setFitHeight(b);

    return bImage2;

}
```

and this is the code of rotating button where I put the rotated image in the imageview :

```
   @FXML
    private void rotation15(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        BufferedImage img2 = rotate(grp_img.get(0), 15);
        view.setImage(convert(img2)));

    }
```

what should I do ? help me please !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but try

```
BufferedImage bImage2 = op.createCompatibleDestImage(bImage, null);
op.filter(bImage, bImage2);
```